# How do i push an object into an array which is inside an object which is also inside an another array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, rest

I want to push an object into an array which is inside another object which is inside an array,

[image]

As in the above picture `likes` = `vote` I have changed that later on,

But I am not able to push an object inside this vote array
I am using this code to push into an array

```
 Question.updateOne(
      { _id: questionId, comments: { $elemMatch: { _id: commentId } } },
      { $push: { "comments.$.vote": { userId } } }
    )
```

I don't know what is wrong here, in the console it shows 200 status but it is not added to the database.

Comment: can you post a sample document so that we can write query.

Comment: where is the "vote" field i dont see it

Comment: i dont know if this is the best idea to go with `push` since you can like it multiple times. i would go with 1 single array witch holds IDs  and add new ids with `addToSet`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with destructuring? i.e. if you have array of likes, you can do this:

myArray= [...myArray, {myNewObject: data}]

Comment: I got the solution ,